# ReactJS: Pass sibling component data into conditional components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

I have a directory structure as below screenshot.

[image]

While doing login from the `LoginComponent` I would like to pass the login data to the `UserProfileComponent` and if not logged in then the `DefaultCompoent` will be loaded by default.

For this I have managed the components as below.

```js
LandingComponent.js
export default function LandingComponent(props) {

  const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false);
  const [userName, setUserName] = useState('')
  useEffect(() => {
    setIsLoggedIn(true)
  });

  return (
    <main>
    {
      isLoggedIn ? <UserProfileComponent setUserName={setUserName} /> : <DefaultComponent userName={userName} />
    }
      
    </main>
  )
}
```

DefaultComponent.js

```js
export default function DefaultComponent(props) {
    return (
        <p>Hello User</p>
    )
}
```

UserProfileComponent.js

```js
export default function UserProfileComponent(props) {
    return (
        <p>Hello {userName}</p>
    )
}
```

LoginComponent.js

```js
export default function LoginComponent(props) {
    const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
    const [userPassword, setPassword] = useState("");

    const loginUser = async event => {
    event.preventDefault()
    axios.post(`{api_endpoint}/login`, data)
    .then((response) => {
        const userDetails = response.data
    })
  })

  return ( 
    <form onSubmit={loginUser}>
      <input
        value={email}
        type="email"
        onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
      />
      <input
        value={userPassword}
        onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
        type="password"
        id="password"
        placeholder="Password"
        required
      />
      <div className="col-2">
        <input type="submit" name="" value="Login" />
      </div>
    </form>
  )
}
```

So, how can I manage to pass the login_api response data from this `LoginComponent` to `UserProfileComponent` using hooks ?

Comment: Either use Redux OR Context API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [context api](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html):

- Create and export the context:

  ```
  export const AuthContext = React.createContext();
  ```
- Add a new state and wrap component into the context provider in *pages/index.js*:

  ```
  export default function Home() {
  const [userData, setUserData] = React.useState(null);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Head>
        <title>Sample App</title>
      </Head>
      <AuthContext.Provider value={{ userData, setUserData }}>
        <HeaderComponent />
        <LandingComponent />
      </AuthContext.Provider>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
  }
  ```
- Access and update the context in the `LoginComponent`:

  ```
  export default function LoginComponent(props) {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [userPassword, setPassword] = useState("");
  const { setUserData } = React.useContext(AuthContext);

  const loginUser = async event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    axios.post(`{api_endpoint}/login`, data).then(response => {
      // Update the context variable
      setUserData(response.data);
    });
  };

  return <div />;
  }
  ```
- Access the context in the `UserProfileComponent`:

  ```
  export default function UserProfileComponent(props) {
  const { userData } = React.useContext(AuthContext);

  if (!userData) {
    return "Loading...";
  }

  // do something with userData

  return <p>Hello {userName}</p>;
  }
  ```

As you can see, you can use the [useContext](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext) hook to access the values. An alternative would be to wrap the respective component in an `<AuthProvider.Consumer />` tag.

**EDIT:**

I updated the answer and moved the context to the *Home* Component.

Comment: Okay !!! Let me try and will update you. 
Thanks for the super quick response.

Comment: Hey, I have tried this and getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'setUserData' of undefined https://prnt.sc/10lylt8, any clues ? Also review updated question about attached codesandbox sample.

Comment: There is a typo in the `LandingComponent` file. It should be `userData` instead of `userDate` and also in `UserProfile` the {} are missing around the import of the context.

Comment: Also in the `AuthContext.Provider` you used `{()}` instead of `{{}}`.

Comment: Hey, I have fixed the typos, but still getting the same error from `LoginComponent`,  https://lf92f.sse.codesandbox.io/ 
https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-montalcini-lf92f?file=/components/Landing/Authentication/Login.js

Comment: Ok, the problem is that `Login` is not a child of *Landing/index*. The solution to that is to move the context provider into the root index file and wrap it around`<HeaderComponent />` and `<LandingComponent/>`.

Comment: Can not get this wrap around of `<HeaderComponent />` and `<LandingComponent />` , can you please update the answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229961/discussion-between-tma-and-gh05d).

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem by 2 methods

1. Create a parent component for your sibling and maintain state in parent and pass it as props to its child components
2. Use state management tools like react context API or Redux to avoid passing props to child elements(Prop Drilling)

**Method 1:**

Create a new component eg: Parent.js

```
export default function Parent() {
//Maintain State here
const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false);

return (
  <main>
   {/*Pass your state to childs as prop*/}
   <ChildComponent1 isLoggedIn={isLoggedIn} />
   <ChildComponent2 isLoggedIn={isLoggedIn} />
  </main>
);
}
```

**Method 2:**

State management using React Context API or Redux

For `React Context` check this tutorial: https://youtu.be/35lXWvCuM8o

For `Redux` check this tutorial: https://youtu.be/CVpUuw9XSjY

Comment: Yes I am already following @Gh05d answer, but stuck at one point. 
Thx for the youtube reference links.